# Is it possible to convert the Tree object in Biopython to Newick format?

Tags: cluster-computing, biopython

I used Bio.Cluster's treecluster that results in a Tree object. 
I am clustering a gene expression matrix. 
I want an easy way to traverse this tree and add some extra features (some extra information like p-values or term names for every node I want), if necessary. 
I found that a good package for this kind of work is ete2, but this needs the tree as Newick string.

Is there a function that can convert the Tree object to Newick or do you know any better way than ete2?

Thanks in advance, 
L.

Answer (score 0):

Bio.Cluster.Tree to newick format, example:

> input file **cyano.txt** [github](https://github.com/simonvh/gimmemotifs/blob/master/src/Algorithm-Cluster-1.49/data/cyano.txt)

```
gene    0   15min   1hour   6hours  15hours
sll0617 0.0 -0.141164092921 -0.564656371686 -0.219393769051 -0.582969948517
slr0452 0.0 -0.124988599702 -0.499954398807 0.195680498436  0.0781478593432
slr1513 0.0 0.788547158236  0.228594792282  0.255819396258  0.304823683415
sll1471 0.0 -0.770355431265 -1.10115338201  -1.00607440632  -0.834932250086
sll1694 0.0 -0.328239937586 -2.16037133914  -1.184544471    -1.36760041273
sll0430 0.0 2.57611845993   0.920296714116  0.331897478085  0.353984672049
sll0851 0.0 -0.260488607867 -1.04195443147  -0.870951657169 -0.563146663432
sll1260 0.0 0.488375211397  1.03336768086   1.05808458732   1.10257501897
sll1031 0.0 2.22636090218   1.2737708006    1.22441048661   1.13556192142
.....
```

use treecluster in `python` ([view example source](http://biopython-cn.readthedocs.org/zh_CN/latest/en/chr15.html))

```
from Bio import Cluster
handle = open("cyano.txt")
record = Cluster.read(handle)
handle.close()
genetree = record.treecluster(method='s')
genetree.scale()
exptree = record.treecluster(dist='u', transpose=1)
record.save("cyano_result", genetree, exptree)
```

> This will create the files `cyano_result.cdt`, `cyano_result.gtr`, and `cyano_result.atr`

now, we can use `R` and Bioconductor to convert atr to newick

Install the latest release of R, then get the latest version of Bioconductor by starting R and entering the commands

```
#optional, for install bioconductor and ctc library
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite()
biocLite("ctc")

#code to convert atr to newick
library("ctc")
h <- xcluster2r("cyano_result.atr")
write(hc2Newick(h),file='cyano_result.newick')
```

in `cyano_result`, we get:

```
(1:0.356996468574314,
  (2:0.0826361905178331,
    (5:0.0469498559561281,
     (3:0.513417484951725,4:0.513417484951725)
    :0.0469498559561281)
  :0.0826361905178331)
:0.356996468574314);
```

obtaining the following plot

[image: tree view]